# FFMPEG Install/enable 'libfdk_aac' after installed FFMPEG via PPA

Tags: ffmpeg

I have linux MINT 17.3 Kernel 4.4.0-81 all update available. (For different reasons I can't move to newer version of ubuntu/mint)

I have installed FFMPEG via PPA (NOT from compiling the source):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3 -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ffmpeg
```

Then I tried to install libfdk-aac with guide:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Quick/libfdk-aac

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config autoconf automake libtool
git clone https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac.git
cd fdk-aac
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

But I'm still receive from FFMPEG: "unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'"

**How can I check if "libfdk_aac' is correctly installed and HOW CAN I ACTIVATE / ENABLE the 'libfdk_aac' on FFMPEG?**

If is not possible in my situation, and if I'm obliged to remove all ffmpeg and follow this:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg does not have a "plug-n-play" codec system. If you want to add another external codec you must compile FFmpeg.

Alternatively, you could find a static `ffmpeg` binary that includes your desired codecs, but this is not a likely option due to the non-free/GPL incompatible situation of the fdk-aac license.

Your best option if you want to use libfdk_aac is to follow the compile guide you linked to. You can even keep the `ffmpeg` you installed from that PPA because the guide does not interfere with any existing repository `ffmpeg`.